# document.querySelectorAll to make dropdown selections using Chrome Console

Tags: javascript

I'm having a tough time getting document.querySelectorAll to use pattern recognition. I'm needing to find all dropdowns on a page that have a name ending with [1] and set that value to Option 1, then do the same for all dropdowns ending in [2] and set that value to Option 2.

I've tried various versions of this to get them just to list inside of the console:
document.querySelectorAll('select[name$=[1]]').forEach(function(node) {console.log(node.options[node.selectedIndex].value);});

But I think I'm getting hung up on the extra square brackets. I've tried escaping, removing, quoting, but I can only get the query to work with the specific name, not the ends with option, or using just the starts with option for the word role since it has no square brackets:
document.querySelectorAll('select[name^="role"]').forEach(function(node) {console.log(node.options[node.selectedIndex].value);});

So for actually changing the value, this works for a specific entry:
document.querySelector('select[name*="role[10][1]"]').value = "682"

But trying this to get all occurrences doesn't have any impact:
document.querySelector('select[name$="[1]"]').value = "682"

```html
<table class="map-table user-sync">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
                <th>External Role</th>
                <th>Internal Role</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td>First Role</td>
                <td><select name="role[10][1]">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">Do Not Sync</option>
                    <option value="683">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="682">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="680">Option 3</option>
                    <option value="681">Option 4</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
        </tr>
                            <tr>
                <td>Second Role</td>
                <td><select name="role[10][1]">
                    <option value="0" selected="selected">Do Not Sync</option>
                    <option value="683">Option 1</option>
                    <option value="682">Option 2</option>
                    <option value="680">Option 3</option>
                    <option value="681">Option 4</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
              </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `document.querySelectorAll("yourSelectorHere")` to get all occurrences and update each occurrence from there.

In your example, `document.querySelector('select[name$="[1]"]').value = "682"` will only get the first occurrence it finds, which in this case, will only update the first occurrence.

Here's a working example:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('select[name$="[1]"]')
.forEach(element => {
  element.value = "683";
});
```

```html
<table class="map-table user-sync">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>External Role</th>
    <th>Internal Role</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First Role</td>
    <td><select name="role[10][1]">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">Do Not Sync</option>
      <option value="683">Option 1</option>
      <option value="682">Option 2</option>
      <option value="680">Option 3</option>
      <option value="681">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second Role</td>
    <td><select name="role[10][1]">
      <option value="0" selected="selected">Do Not Sync</option>
      <option value="683">Option 1</option>
      <option value="682">Option 2</option>
      <option value="680">Option 3</option>
      <option value="681">Option 4</option>
    </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Thanks for that response, that does indeed work, I forgot to copy in the "all" that I was trying to use as well, I had reduced the scope to a single instance for troubleshooting.

So, I recreated the page on a clean server and it does indeed work, but there appears to be something in the production site I'm working with that is interfering, as I can't get anything to update unless I name the specific unique class name.

I'll have to look at getting a list of all elements and looping through that I think then. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! 

I see. I'd suggest probably looking into the sequence of events happening on the site you're working on. There could be another script which is doing something with the elements you're targeting like what you said, interfering. Anyways, good luck!